# Generate unique ID in hook_redirect_form

Tags: 7, commerce

I'm trying to write custom payment method for a custom bank gateway (off-site method). bank service expect me to send unique ID for each pay request per `bpPayRequest()` call.

currently I sending `$order->order_id`, but its wrong because: if first request fails this `orderId` is not unique for second `bpPayRequest()` call. so I should create unique ID which is related to $orders. Is there any commerce way for this question?

```
$parameters = array(
  ...
  'orderId' => $order->order_id,
  ...
);
$result = $client->call('bpPayRequest', $parameters, $namespace);
```

Comment: md5($order->order_id . microtime()) immediately comes to mind

Comment: generating unique ID is not the matter, its relation with order is. I think I should do something with `commerce transactions`

Answer (score 0):

```
$unique_id = $order->order_id . '-' . microtime();
```

The advantage of this is you can explode on the - later and get the order id back again.